# Python 3.6 - scipy raising error: NotImplementedError: input type '<U32' not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, filter, scipy

I want to denoise data with `lfilter`.
My code:

```py
    data = []
    with open('Accelerometer.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            data.append(row)
    
    timeInMS = []
    mx = []
    my = []
    mz = []
    for rowIndex in range(0, len(data)):
        print(rowIndex)
        timeInMS.append(data[rowIndex][1])
    
        mx.append(data[rowIndex][2])
        my.append(data[rowIndex][3])
        mz.append(data[rowIndex][4])
    # Data for plotting
    
    n = 15  # the larger n is, the smoother curve will be
    b = [1.0 / n] * n
    a = 1
    
    fMx = lfilter(b, a, mx)
    fMy = lfilter(b, a, my)
    fMz = lfilter(b, a, mz)
    
    # plotting the line 1 points
    plt.plot(timeInMS, fMx, label="x")
    
    # plotting the line 2 points
    plt.plot(timeInMS, fMy, label="y")
    
    # plotting the line 3 points
    plt.plot(timeInMS, fMz, label="z")
    
    plt.xlabel('x - axis')
    plt.ylabel('y - axis')
    plt.title('Changes on Accelerometer')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show() # Display a figure.
```

Accelerometer.csv (1000 lines):

```
Timestamp,Milliseconds,X,Y,Z
2020-10-05 10:19:23,11,0.02633622,0.2633622,9.933543
2020-10-05 10:19:23,18,0.037110128,0.25498247,9.938332
2020-10-05 10:19:23,29,0.034715924,0.25258827,9.939528
2020-10-05 10:19:23,37,0.037110128,0.25139117,9.944317
2020-10-05 10:19:23,47,0.039504327,0.2621651,9.932345
2020-10-05 10:19:23,58,0.035913024,0.25378537,9.927557
2020-10-05 10:19:23,68,0.037110128,0.2633622,9.931149
2020-10-05 10:19:23,78,0.027533319,0.25857377,9.932345
2020-10-05 10:19:23,87,0.02633622,0.25258827,9.94312
...
...
...
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Accelerometer/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    fMx = lfilter(b, a, mx)
  File "Accelerometer\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 1883, in lfilter
    raise NotImplementedError("input type '%s' not supported" % dtype)
NotImplementedError: input type '<U32' not supported
```

Comment: Could you add the `import` statements of your script?

Comment: Also,a little print tells you that `mx=['X', '0.02633622', '0.037110128', ... `. Probably not what you want.

Comment: I fixed the code and now it works! Thank you guys all te help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really helps to use pandas `pd.read_csv()` to read in your file. This would automatically put the data into a handy format. Then you can directly use `mx = data['X']`.

Without pandas, you run into problems such as here, where you forget to skip the header, and furthermore your data are all in string format instead of numeric. It also converts the date and time from a string format to a real date-time format.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import lfilter

data = pd.read_csv('Accelerometer.csv')

n = 15  # the larger n is, the smoother curve will be
b = [1.0 / n] * n
a = 1

fMx = lfilter(b, a, data['X'])
fMy = lfilter(b, a, data['Y'])
fMz = lfilter(b, a, data['Z'])

# plotting the line 1 points
plt.plot(data['Milliseconds'], fMx, label="x")

# plotting the line 2 points
plt.plot(data['Milliseconds'], fMy, label="y")

# plotting the line 3 points
plt.plot(data['Milliseconds'], fMz, label="z")

plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.title('Changes on Accelerometer')
plt.legend()
plt.show()  # Display a figure.
```

[image: example plot]